# Can't find package xml while executing. Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xml

```
astroboy@MyUbuntu:~$ ds9 &

[1] 365

astroboy@MyUbuntu:~$ Error in startup script: can't find package xml

    while executing

"package require xml"

    ("x11" arm line 9)

    invoked from within

"switch $ds9(wm) {

    x11 {

    # set to absolute path so that if -cd command is used,

    # so we can still find our files
    set ds9(root) [file normalize [..."
    (file "/usr/share/saods9/library/ds9.tcl" line 197)
```

Need to use it for iraf but it doesn't work. Please, suggest how to solve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If files are missing files or XML support is unavailable, then the package probably hasn't been installed properly. Do `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get check` first. If there are no errors, reinstall the package.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug in Ubuntu 16.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/saods9/+bug/1782692). Just do a

```
$ sudo apt-get install tclxml
```

in a terminal window. Or upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04, which also gives you an IRAF package.

Answer (score 0):

ds9 should be an executable.

First try to check if it is executable with the following command:

```
$ ldd `which ds9`
```

If the answer is:

```
not a dynamic executable
```

Then, you must download from the official site ds9 ( http://ds9.si.edu/site/Download.html ) and install it. Firsr, untar the downloaded file

```
$ sudo tar xzvf ds9.linux_distribution.tar.gz
```

Move

```
$ sudo mv ds9 /usr/local/bin
```

change permissions

```
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ds9
```

And, finally run:

```
$ ds9
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be duplicated with [other post](https://superuser.com/questions/1482228/cant-run-saos-ds9-program-missing-xml-ubuntu-18-04/1491855#1491855). Since I'm not allowed to comment, I replying with this answer.

Install the official Ubuntu ds9 (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install saods9`).

If you are using Conda/Anaconda environment, I found your error with both Anaconda2-2019.10 and Anaconda3-2020.02. To solve it, downgrade the default ds9 v8.0 to v7.4 with the command `conda install ds9"<8"` or `conda install ds9"=7.4"`. That worked for me (Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 LTS).