# Can't run SAO's ds9 program. Missing xml. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, xml

After installing saods9 on Ubuntu 18.04, I tried running

```
$ ds9 &
```

And recieved:

```
     Error in startup script: can't find package xml
         while executing
     "package require xml"
         ("x11" arm line 10)
         invoked from within
     "switch $ds9(wm) {
         x11 {
        # set to absolute path so that if -cd command is used,
        # so we can still find our files
        set ds9(root) [file normalize [..."
         (file "/usr/share/saods9/library/ds9.tcl" line 178)
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

see this link, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/saods9/+bug/1782692
or this [Can't find package xml while executing. Xubuntu 16.04](https://superuser.com/questions/1361857/cant-find-package-xml-while-executing-xubuntu-16-04/1362107)
possibly, if you try "sudo ds9" then you can open the software.

Answer (score 0):

Install the official Ubuntu ds9 (`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install saods9`).

If you are using Conda/Anaconda environment, I found your error with both Anaconda2-2019.10 and Anaconda3-2020.02. To solve it, downgrade the default ds9 v8.0 to v7.4 with the command `conda install ds9"<8"`. That worked for me (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

Comment: A friend of my just tried it on Ubuntu 18.04, and he needed to change to `conda install ds9"=7.4"` to make it work.